# Download xlsx file passed from nodejs to frontend angularjs

Tags: angularjs, node.js, download

I have a JSON array of objects that is a result of a function in nodejs.  I use json2xls to convert that to an excel file, and it downloads to the server (not in a public folder, and is formatted correctly in Excel).

I would like to send a response to the frontend with the json results (to display as a preview) and show a button they can click to download the xlsx file OR display the JSON results and automatically download the file.

But I can't get it, and I've tried so many things I'm going crazy.
My controller code (the part that creates the xls file):

```
 var xls = json2xls(results,{});
 var today = (new Date()).toDateString('yyyy-mm-dd');
 var str = today.replace(/\s/g, '');
 var fileName = "RumbleExport_"+ str +".xlsx";
 var file = fs.writeFileSync(fileName,xls,'binary');
 res.download('/home/ubuntu/workspace/'+file);
```

The frontend controller:

```
vm.exportData = function(day, event, division) {
        console.log('Export registrations button pressed.', vm.export);
      //send the search parameters to the backend to run checks
        $http.post('/api/exportData', vm.export).then(function(response){
            vm.results = response.data;
            console.log("Results",response);
            vm.exportMessage = "Found " + vm.results.length + " registrations.";
        })
        .catch(function(error){
          vm.exportError = error.data;
        });
    };
```

The view:

```
//display a button to download the export file
<a target="_self" file="{{vm.results}}" download="{{vm.results}}">Download Export File</a>
```

Someone please put me out of my misery.  All the classes I've taken and none have covered this.

Answer (score 1):

I FINALLY got it!  And since I searched forever trying to make something work, I'll share the answer:

On the backend:

```
//save the file to the public/exports folder
var file = fs.writeFileSync('./public/exports/'+fileName,xls,'binary');
//send the results to the frontend
res.json(200).json({results:results, fileName: fileName});
```

On the frontend, use HTML to download a link to the file:

```
<a href="exports/{{fileName}}" download>Save File</a>
```

Comment: Did you install the packages?  I had to require several packages at the top of the page to make it work, which means they needed to be installed with npm

Comment: No, I found an alternate way to do that